# Maximum call stack exceeded on Parse Signup

Tags: javascript, authentication, parse-platform

So I have this simple code in Parse:

```
$('.validatesignupform').click(function(){
var username1 = $("#username1");
var password1 = $("#password1");
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", username1);
user.set("password", password1);
user.signUp(null, {
          success: function(user) {
          // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
          $('.container').append("Hello, "+username+", nice meeting you!");
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
        // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
      });
     });
```

However, upon filling out the signup form, it gives me an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. Any ideas on why? The login works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You send a jQuery object instead of sending the value.

Replace:

```
var username1 = $("#username1");
var password1 = $("#password1");
```

By:

```
var username1 = $("#username1").val();
var password1 = $("#password1").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write any undefined values to your user object, you will get the "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error during signup. I'd check that username1 and password1 exist.